# Spin css anim with jpreloader.js

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

I use jpreloader.js for preload the page. Instead of the script animation, i would like to run mine, colorful spinning circles... but my css animation does not work.

I would like to do this : http://ref.topictimes.com/videos/tech/how-to-create-a-custom-preloading-screen-full-blHZ6zCYvMM.html

I made a fiddle of the whole preloading, jpreloader.js is attached : http://jsfiddle.net/igorlaszlo/dy0snxvr/

In the meantime i checked out if the css animation does not work because of the jquery script but when i try only the animation itself, it is the same result, it does not work : http://jsfiddle.net/igorlaszlo/n1L961dw/1/

The codes only for the css animation :

HTML

```
<div id="overlay">    
    <div id="loader"></div>    
</div>
```

CSS

```
#overlay {
position:fixed;
width:100%;
height:100%;
top:0;
left:0;
z-index:98;
background: #303636;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform:rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform:rotate(0deg);
        transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
        -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform:rotate(360deg);
        transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform:rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform:rotate(0deg);
        transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
        -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform:rotate(360deg);
        transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes spin {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform:rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform:rotate(0deg);
        transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
        -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform:rotate(360deg);
        transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
}
#loader {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    margin:-75px 0 0 -75px;
    border:3px solid transparent;
    border-top-color:#3498db;
    -webkit-border-radius:50%;
    border-radius:50%;
    -webkit-animation:spin 2% linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 2% linear infinite;
    animation:spin 2% linear infinite;
    z-index:100;
}
#loader:before {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    left:5px;
    right:5px;
    bottom:5px;
    border:3px solid transparent;
    border-top-color:#e74c3c;
    -webkit-border-radius:50%;
    border-radius:50%;
    -webkit-animation:spin 3% linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 3% linear infinite;
    animation:spin 3% linear infinite;
}
#loader:after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:15px;
    left:15px;
    right:15px;
    bottom:15px;
    border:3px solid transparent;
    border-top-color:#f9c922;
    -webkit-border-radius:50%;
    border-radius:50%;
    -webkit-animation:spin 1.5% linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 1.5% linear infinite;
    animation:spin 1.5% linear infinite;
}
```

What is wrong with my css animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe somethings not quite good in your css:

```
animation:spin 1.5% linear infinite; <-- check + also see the prefixed ones
```

That **1.5%** should be 1.5**s** not **%**, it stands for *time* so I think it should be specified in *seconds*

Looking at *[animation shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation)* property:

```
Formal syntax: <single-animation-name> || <time> || <timing-function> || <time> || <single-animation-iteration-count> || <single-animation-direction> || <single-animation-fill-mode> || <single-animation-play-state>
```

Check the **[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/zoo9b820/1/)** and hope this helps you.

Comment: Good job !  In spite that i checked out the codes hundred times line by line, my eyes are tired, i was front of the computer during the whole day... Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: @IgorLaszlo Yeah, we've all been there, something so small breaks a code to pieces. Anyway, glad to help out!